# How to write functions with array? C programming

Tags: c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

     void main()
    {
        int storage, display_amount, item_amount, a, week;
        char storage_size[50], input_item[50];
        char item[50][100];
        float input_price;
        float price[50];

        printf("Storage Size:");
        printf("\n[1] Small Box (50cm x 50cm)-RM5 per week");
        printf("\n[2] Regular Box (100cm x 100cm)-RM15 per week");
        printf("\n[3] Large Box (200cm x 200cm)-RM25 per week");
        printf("\nPlease choose your storage: ");
        scanf("%i", &storage);

        if (storage == 1){
            strcpy(storage_size, "Small Box");
            display_amount = 5;
        }else if (storage == 2){
            strcpy(storage_size, "Regular Box");
            display_amount = 8;
        }else{
            strcpy(storage_size, "Large Box");
            display_amount = 12;
        }
        printf("\nYou have selected %s. How many items to display? (up to %i items): ", storage_size, display_amount);
        scanf("%i", &item_amount);



        for(int a = 0; a < item_amount; a++){
                printf("Item %i: ", a+1);
                scanf("%s", input_item);
                strcpy(item[a], input_item);

                printf("Price: RM ");
                scanf("%f", &input_price);
                price[a] = input_price;
            }

        printf("How many weeks to display the items?: ");
        scanf("%i", &week);

        printf("\nYou have entered %i item(s) to be displayed in your storage.", item_amount);

        printf("\n---------------------------------------");
        printf("\nItem                       Price       ");
        printf("\n---------------------------------------");

        for(int a = 0; a < item_amount; a++){
                printf("\n%s", item[a]);
                printf("                        RM %.2f", price[a]);
        }

        printf("\n---------------------------------------");
    }
```

I'm very new to C programming and I'm trying to write the codes above inside a function. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out the specific arguments for the function and the arrays make me even more confused. Can anyone help me to write all the code inside a function?

Comment: Wait. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You should give some specifics about the function: at least inputs and outputs. It is not very clear from the question/code.

Comment: Nitpick, main is a function, so the code is already inside a function. How should it be divided intonother functions?

Answer (score 1):

> .... I'm trying to write the codes above in function. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out the specific arguments for which function and the arrays were are making me even confused.

When passing an array to a function, the array decays into a pointer of the same type as the array. So a function that shall receive an array is really just passed a pointer to the array. Like:

```
void foo(int arr[])  // or void foo(int* arr)
{
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2 * arr[0];
    ...
}

int arr[10];
foo(arr);
```

One "problem" with passing arrays is that the function can't tell how many items that the array has. Therefore it's common to pass a size as well.

Like

```
void foo(int arr[], int size)  // or void foo(int* arr, int size)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<size; ++j) arr[j] = j;
}

int arr[10];
foo(arr, 10);       // or better foo(arr, sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]);
```

So a function to print the prices in your code could look:

```
void print_prices(float* price, int item_amount)
{
    for(int a = 0; a < item_amount; a++)
    {
            printf("RM %.2f\n", price[a]);
    }

}

print_prices(price, item_amount);
```

Passing an array of strings (like your `item`) is a bit more complex as it is really a 2 dimensional array. The function needs to be told about the size of the first dimension in order to use the array correctly.

Here is a simple example of an array of strings.

```
void foo(int n, int m, char s[][m])  // Notice s[][m]
{
    int j;
    for (j=0; j<n; ++j) printf("%s\n", s[j]);
}

int main()
{
    char s[3][32] = {"abc", "defghi", "xyzzyx"};
    foo(3, 32, s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at pointers (basically the address of a variable or in case of arrays the address of the first element).
Arrays (and also struct types) are passed to functions by address, does not matter if if at higher level for you they are inputs or outputs. When you pass a variable (or array) by address, the modifications you do inside the function are also visible outside the function (you are modifying the value inside an address).

You must be careful to not exceed the length of the array you passed as input.

```
int exampleF(int[50] array, char anotherInput)
{
    array[0]=10;//this modification will be valid also outside the function
    return 0;
}
```